# BLDC motor and bullet connectors getting hot

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, lipo, remote-control, overheat

I am using the following components:

1. Lemon RC 3S-2200mAh 25C/ 50C (burst) LiPo battery
2. Readytosky 80A ESC
3. DYS D2726-6 BLDC (2200kV BLDC motor)

I am testing out the components with 1045 (10 in, 4.5 pitch) propeller.

I ran at 50% throttle for 1 min and observed that my motor - stator got hot along with the bullet connectors connecting the ESC to the motor.

I want to know why this is happening and how can I correct this if is is a problem.

I am very new to the hobby of RC planes and could really use guidance.

Comment: Sounds normal. There’s a lot of current flowing so that causes things to heat up. The RC forums would be a better source of information methinks as your question is very specific to RC.

Comment: Define "hot". Too hot to touch? OK.  Insulation started smoking? Not OK. Why? I^2*R losses.

Comment: Is that motor designed to operate with 3S packs? Don't the motors usually say how many S you can use? Maybe it is a 2S motor? I am not that into RC so I am not sure. But the motor does have to match the battery voltage. If the bullet connectors are getting hot it could be bad solder joint or maybe you should use bigger bullets (or maybe you just need to use a lower voltage).

Comment: Thank you for the replies people, much appreciated and yes the motor is rated to work with 3S pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is inappropriate. 1 minute is way too long for static test. 10 seconds maybe. Static testing for a whole minute on the ground when these are designed rely on the air cooling from being flown through the air? Of course it's going to get hot. You're not supposed to run these systems statically for long. Your motors, ESC, and battery will not like it.

Model helicopters have fans to cool everything because they don't move through the air like a plane.

But you need a thermometer to know if it is really too hot or not. Too hot to touch is only 50C or 60C. Not to mention a propeller spinning and moving through the air is loaded differently than one spinning in still air. Diameter-pitch ratio of 2:1 isn't too bad but as you get to a more square propeller there are bigger differences between static and in-air testing.